# Reconstructing an exception from an extracted traceback

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, traceback

I have a dict like this:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    ["/path/to/some/code.py", 10, "some_function", "do_something()"],
    ["/path/to/some/code.py", 20, "do_something", "raise MyException('aaaa')"]
  ],
  "errorType": "MyException",
  "errorMessage": "aaaa",
}
```

I can make it pretty with `traceback.format_list` but I was wondering if there was a way to reconstruct the actual exception and raise it. I figure I can dynamically create the exception type and use the same message but how can I preserve the stack trace?

edit: so, I've tried this, but I'm stuck on turning the `stackTrace` in my dict into a `traceback` object. I've no idea how to do it - [apparently it is very difficult to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138440/how-to-create-a-traceback-object) so I'm wondering if there's a different way to accomplish what I want.

```
raise type(mydict['errorType'], (Exception,), {}), mydict['errorMessage'], traceback???
```

Comment: Maybe just use an ordered dict? Not sure what it is you are asking though..

Comment: I want to raise an exception with that type, value, and traceback as if it had occurred in my code, even though all I have is this dict.