# Can I get AdminEmailHandler to give me a traceback for logging.error level?

Tags: django

I have my Django instance configured with

```
    "mail_admins": {
        "level": "ERROR",
        "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
    },
```

When I get `logging.error()` messages, I don't know where they were generated and would like to in order to possibly change their level to squelch noise.

Adding `include_html=True` did not add a stack trace.

I've looked through `AdminEmailHandler` and I haven't found an obvious way to hook this capability in.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem that straightforward.  First, [prior to Python 3.7 there isn't a supported way to make a traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54653137/2077386).  Prior to Django 3.1, [DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER) doesn't exist.

The smarter way to do this is probably just to [track the line number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533077/2077386) with `logging.Formatter`.